# Update-AzureRmVmss : Required parameter 'adminPassword' is missing (null)

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to run a PowerShell vmss custom extension script on scale set.

I get this error when it tries to run the Update-AzureRmVmss command
Update-AzureRmVmss : Required parameter 'adminPassword' is missing (null).
ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
ErrorMessage: Required parameter 'adminPassword' is missing (null).
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request

```
$customConfig = @{
 "fileUris" = @("https://$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/script.ps1");
"commandToExecute" = "PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\script.ps1";
};
# Add the extension to the config
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMScaleSetName $vmssname
Add-AzureRmVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -Publisher Microsoft.Compute -Type CustomScriptExtension -TypeHandlerVersion 2.0 -Name "runscript" -Setting $customConfig
# Send the new config to Azure
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name "runscript" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue.
The -Name needs to be scaleset name. The code I got from online had the name as the name of the script which was wrong.

```
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name "scalsetname" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the PowerShell cmdlet or CLI commands to add an extension directly..

PowerShell: Add-AzureRmVmssExtension 
CLI: az vmss extension set

The Azure Cloud Shell has a built in authenticated version of CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter for Update-AzureRmVmss is -VMScaleSetName which also has an alias called Name.
I was also getting the same error using -Name parameter,
but when I tried using `-VMScaleSetName` in place of `-Name`, I do not see the error.

Here is the official documentation for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/update-azurermvmss?view=azurermps-6.9.0

```
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMScaleSetName "scalesetname" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

Answer (score 0):

If found this thread by searching for `Required parameter 'adminPassword' is missing (null)`, but my solution was a different one.

Turns out that you get this message also if your chosen password does not match the security requirements of the VM (or whatever) you are installing. It is a confusing way to express that issue, to say the least, so maybe this helps someone.